# Why does vue still report jsx errors? Although an error is reported, it can be executed normally. What is the reason?

Tags: vue3-openlayers

Why does vue still report jsx errors? Although an error is reported, it can be executed normally. What is the reason?

```js
<el-submenu index="1">
< const ElMenuItem: unknown
    JSx element type 'E1MenuItem' does not have any construct signature or call signature. ts (2604)>
< View issues No quick fixes available>
< el-menu-item index="1-1">item1</el-menu-item>
< el-menu-item index="1-2">item1</el-menu-item>
</el-submenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem with the volar plugin. Try to upgrade the version of the plugin to 0.36.1, or you can add some configuration and add such a configuration to tsconfig.json.

```js
{
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "experimentalSuppressInvalidJsxElementTypeErrors": true
  }
}
```